# how to decrypt after adding random letter after every two letters javascript

Tags: javascript, function, loops

```
const alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

function encrypt (message, shiftValue)
{   
    let encryptedMessage = ''; // somewhere for the message to be stored
    for (i = 0; i < message.length; i++){
      let char = message[i].toLowerCase(); // each character made lowercase

      if (alphabet.includes(char)) { // if alphabet includes the character
        const idx = alphabet.indexOf(char);// find its index
        const newIdx = (idx + shiftValue) % alphabet.length;// then add the shift value to it     while going through the alphabet
        encryptedMessage += alphabet[newIdx] // add/store it as the message

        if ((i + 1) % 2 === 0) {
          const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * 26);
           encryptedMessage += alphabet[randomIndex];// every two character a random letter is     added
        }
      } else {
        encryptedMessage += char;
      }
    }

  return encryptedMessage;
}

function decrypt (encryptedMessage, shiftValue)
{
  let decryptedMessage = '';

  for (i = 0; i < encryptedMessage.length; i++){
    const char = encryptedMessage[i].toLowerCase();

    if (alphabet.includes(char)) {
        const idx = alphabet.indexOf(char);
        const newIdx = (idx - shiftValue  + alphabet.length) % alphabet.length;
        decryptedMessage += alphabet[newIdx]
    }else {
    decryptedMessage += char;

    } 
  }
  // Your decryption code here
  return decryptedMessage;
}
```

I'm brand new to coding and have used many an online resource to scramble this together. I even consulted chatgpt at one point and feel so dumb for that. I mainly would like some feedback on how the code is and to help me solve a problem that I cant quite find online or seem to figure out myself. below the requirements will be posted

1. **Implementing the Encryption Algorithm of Caesar's Cipher**

   - Step 1: Take a plaintext message and a shift value and return an encrypted string. If the message includes a character out of the alphabet, pass it as is to the encrypted string.
   - Step 2: After every two letters, insert a random letter from the alphabet.
2. **Implementing the Decryption Algorithms of Caesar's Cipher**

   - Take in the encrypted message and a shift value and return the original plaintext message.
   - Accurately reverse the encryption process to retrieve the original message.
3. **Decrypting the Secret Message**

   - Iueuan jrxuq cjythdykwxaj mixkqtaeml ebv wHenckvbkei rqdmt fHukckvi.r Jbxuihus, tmxayiwfuxh sjxau amenhtv 'zQkhhuubyjkit' yjew jhxux mxydatij. zJxmu hvymhihj ajel kldlsuyjb dyju yid uekdh qIbkqsxa xsxqqdvduzb wuqzhdoi qjxwu waueo xjem jfxuy dpuntj dgkvuiwj.
   - Decrypt the above secret message using 42 as the shift value and complete the quest.

My main question in all of this is how do I reverse the fact that a random letter is added after every two letters to properly decrypt not only the messages I put through it but the required message. I get most of the message i put through back. The required decryption I only ever get back undefined.

This is my first post on here, I hope I've formatted and asked this properly thank you to any and all who help me brainstorm this!

I've not tried anything as of yet I'm still very new and feel like I cheated even scraping together what I have above by looking up most of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are two problems with your decrypt function:

1. newIdx could be very negative value, for example if incoming letter is `a`, `idx` will be 0, so `0-42+26 = -16`, this is why you're getting undefined
2. you know that encrypt inserted random symbol every 2 symbols, you just remove them or ignore

```js
const alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

function decrypt (encryptedMessage, shiftValue)
{
  let decryptedMessage = '';

  for (i = 0; i < encryptedMessage.length; i++){
    if ( (i+1) % 3 != 0) { // ignore random insertions
      const char = encryptedMessage[i].toLowerCase();
      const idx = alphabet.indexOf(char);
      if (idx >= 0) {
          let newIdx = idx - shiftValue;
          while (newIdx < 0) newIdx += alphabet.length; // here is how you avoid negative indexes
          decryptedMessage += alphabet[newIdx % alphabet.length];
      } else {
        decryptedMessage += char;
      } 
    }
  }
  // Your decryption code here
  return decryptedMessage;
}

console.log(decrypt('Iueuan jrxuq cjythdykwxaj mixkqtaeml ebv wHenckvbkei rqdmt fHukckvi.r Jbxuihus, tmxayiwfuxh sjxau amenhtv \'zQkhhuubyjkit\' yjew jhxux mxydatij. zJxmu hvymhihj ajel kldlsuyjb dyju yid uekdh qIbkqsxa xsxqqdvduzb wuqzhdoi qjxwu waueo xjem jfxuy dpuntj dgkvuiwj.', 42));
```

Comment: I appreciate your input very much. this has given me a lot to think about in terms of my current understanding of code and the code that I've written. thank you very much!!